# Implementing checkbox list from list in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, checkboxlist

I've seen the other threads on the subject, but am having trouble with what I believe is the correct syntax/setup. Ultimately the controller is not able to see the contents of the Role list when it is being returned from an edit.

View

```
@model Models.Volunteer

            @foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.Selected" />
                <label asp-for="@item.Selected">@item.RoleName</label>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.RoleId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.RoleName" />
                <br />
            }

<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Model

```
public abstract class BaseVolunteer
{
    [Key]
    public int Recno { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Roles")]
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public String RoleId { get; set; }
    public String RoleName { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Recno,FirstName,LastName,Email,City,Roles")] Volunteer volunteer)
    {
}
```

The volunteer object in the controller correctly returns the other values... but the Roles object is NULL despite being properly populated for display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the array-indexer so the model-binder knows the index of each item:

```
@for( Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.Roles.Length; i++ ) {
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Roles[i].Selected" />
    <label asp-for="@Model.Roles[i].Selected">@Model.Roles[i].RoleName</label>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Roles[i].RoleId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Roles[i].RoleName" />
    <br />
}
```

This will be rendered into something like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[0].Selected" value="false" id="Roles_0__Selected" />
    <label for="Roles_0__Selected">Admin</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[0].RoleId" value="10" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[0].RoleName" value="Admin" />
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[1].Selected" value="false" id="Roles_1__Selected" />
    <label for="Roles_1__Selected">Users</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[1].RoleId" value="120" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[1].RoleName" value="Users" />
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[2].Selected" value="false" id="Roles_2__Selected" />
    <label for="Roles_2__Selected">Guests</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[2].RoleId" value="123" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Roles[2].RoleName" value="Guestsd />
    <br />
```

Notice how the `name=""` values contain the index which the Model binder can use.

Comment: Thanks! I'm obviously new to .NET core... but this makes me wonder why they support the foreach syntax if the model binder doesn't recognize it properly.